# How to find the indexes of the minimum value in whole dataframe?

Tags: r

Assume i have the following dataset

```
dt<-data.frame(id=1:10,X=sample(10),Y=sample(10))
dt<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist(dt)))
for(i in 1:nrow(dt))
  dt[i,i]<-NA
```

and **i need to find the indexes of minimum value in whole dataframe?** (row, and column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `which` and set `arr.ind = TRUE` to get the row and column. Also set `na.rm = TRUE` so that the missing values are removed when obtaining the minimum.

```
which(dt == min(dt, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
#  row col
#2   2   1
#1   1   2
```